# Get row index from row id and table id

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get Index no of a row when hyperlink is clicked i am passing some other data too from this tag

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="EditDoctorRow(' + RowCountDoctorVisit + ');">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

I tried

```
$('table#DoctorVisit tr#' + RowCount).index()
$('table#DoctorVisit tr#' + RowCount).closest.index()
```

But both are not working

Comment: Complete code means how I am creating dynamic table and all that? I just want to fetch index number using row id

Comment: Where you're trying to get the `index`?

Comment: in function which is called by clicking on <a href> tag

Comment: Why are you using an A element if you don't want a link or anchor? Use a styled span or div.

Comment: I am creating a popup editing dialog form which is filling up using row id and table id then i want to save the editted data on same index by deleting and re inserting new data

Comment: What exactly is `RowCountDoctorVisit`? Do you get unique id for `tr` within table `DoctorVisit`?

Comment: Please post screenshot of the table row(s) / whole table (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the nearest row ID of a selected element.

```
var row_id = $(this).closest('tr').index()
```

In reply to your comment (again): http://jsfiddle.net/vcLvxycv/4/

This is independent of the row ID, will return the index as requested!

---

OK! Final edit I think I know what you mean. In the input box type one of the row IDs, it will then return that row's index

http://jsfiddle.net/vcLvxycv/7/

Comment: I have dynamic <a href> tag i wont be knowing the id and there migh be 2 more <a href> tag with same id  in different tables so i wont to get it using table

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This will apply to any <a> tags. If you want to narrow it down to some just use their class or location.

Comment: This is not the way i want its working but I want to find the index number using table id and row id its for some purpose

Comment: Ok. So what do you mean by 'index'? You want to find the row id? table id? Please describe what a user might do (i.e. click link) and then what you want to happen.

Comment: Index of a row i already have row id and table id. User will click on <a href> tag it will show some values on click and then after changing those value it will store the entire row on same index number. Its pop up editing type of thing

Comment: Rows don't have an index property. Do you mean index as-in top row is 0, second row is 1, third row is 2 etc?

Comment: Man I have tried this but I want to find it using row id and table id if there is any way to do that

Comment: Gr8 its working but dont know why I am getting first row index as 2

Comment: Ok I forgot about it count header as 1 row ty so much